# How to create legend for Plotlines with Highstock of Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have a Highstock graph with Plotlines here: http://jsfiddle.net/qd0rmazg/3/

I'd like to be able to have a legend of Plotlines where, similar to the legend of Series, upon a click Plotlines of a certain category can be made visible or hidden.

In my JSfiddle example, there are 2 categories of Plotlines. Is it possible to toggle the visibility of Plotlines per one category? I couldn't seem to find anything supporting this.

This is how I've created the Plotlines:

```
xAxis: {
   plotLines: [{
      value: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 29), // year, month, day
      width: 1,
      color: 'blue',
      dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
      label: {
          text: 'Category 1',
      },
   }, {
      value: Date.UTC(2016, 11, 12), // year, month, day
      width: 1,
      color: 'green',
      dashStyle: 'Solid',
      label: {
          text: 'Category 2',
      }]
}
```

Comment: There is a feature request for this functionality that you can add your votes/comments to:  https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3009547-plotlines-on-legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no native HC legend for the plot lines. But, you can create your custom legend element on the page and use HC capabilities to show/hide plot lines as in their examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-addplotline/

```
 chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');

 chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
        ....
        id: 'plot-line-1'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment, there is a feature request here:

- https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3009547-plotlines-on-legend

Please add your votes and comments.

Vladimir M provided a good solution to show/hide the plot lines with your own custom legend.

The other common approach is to use a line series as your `plotLine`, which gives you the benefit of the full series functionality.

Example series:

```
{
  name: 'PlotLine',
  type: 'line',
  color: 'rgba(204,0,0,1)',
  data: [25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25]
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nh65m306/

If you need a vertical plot line, the data set up is slightly more complex but still quite feasible.

**{{EDIT to demo vertical plot line:**

First, you;d have to set a min/max for you y axis (could be done programmatically on chart load):

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 75,
  maxPadding: 0
}
```

Then, you specify your data in `[x,y]` pairs, with the `x` values being your `plotLine` value, and the `y` values being your Y axis min and max:

```
data: [[4,0], [4,75]]
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nh65m306/1/

With that method, you could add a series per plot line, or, if you want all of them to be the same legend and settings, you can add multiple by inserting `null` points between your desired lines:

```
data: [[4,0], [4,75], [5,null], [7,0],[7,75]]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nh65m306/2/

Comment: How would you do a vertical plot line with this method?